# Why does this file generate an invisible character?

Tags: php

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]
[image: image4]

I used the same code in the same place with another file, but this issue still occurs. One character is being output. I suspect it's an issue with the file, but I can't pinpoint the problem.

Comment: You probably have a BOM character before `<?php`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: View the files with a hex editor.

Comment: Use <?=123;?> and the problem will be fixed.